# Combine jQuery functions to make simpler

Tags: jquery

I have a simple function that changes the source of an image on mouseover and changes it back on mouseout. It works great but when I try to apply this effect to multiple images with the same class the wrong images are being replaced. So I have written different functions for each mouseover image. It is becoming way too much code. Can someone give me some ideas how I can condense this code to make all images with a certain class switch to their appropriate hover image and back.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var passiveBio = $("#index_container img.bio").attr("src");
var hoverBio = passiveBio.replace(".jpg", "_hover.jpg");
$("#index_container img.bio")
    .mouseover(function() { 
        $(this).attr("src", hoverBio);
        })
    .mouseout(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", passiveBio);
        });
var passiveSamples = $("#index_container img.samples").attr("src");
var hoverSamples = passiveSamples.replace(".jpg", "_hover.jpg");
$("#index_container img.samples")
    .mouseover(function() { 
        $(this).attr("src", hoverSamples);
        })
    .mouseout(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", passiveSamples);
        });
var passiveServices = $("#index_container img.services").attr("src");
var hoverServices = passiveServices.replace(".jpg", "_hover.jpg");
$("#index_container img.services")
    .mouseover(function() { 
        $(this).attr("src", hoverServices);
        })
    .mouseout(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", passiveServices);
    });});
```

This is the div with the images.

```
<div id="index_container">
    <a href="samples.html"><img class="index_box samples" src="images/samples.jpg"/></a>
    <a href="services.html"><img class="index_box services" src="images/services.jpg"/></a>
    <a href="about.html"><img class="index_box bio" src="images/bio.jpg"/></a>
    <img class="index_box" src="images/grey.png"/>
    <img class="index_box" src="images/light_blue.png"/>
    <img class="index_box" src="images/dark_blue.png"/>
    <img class="index_box" src="images/grey.png"/>
    <img class="index_box" src="images/light_blue.png"/>
    <img class="index_box" src="images/dark_blue.png"/>
    <p class="clear"></p>
</div>
```

I have tried making all the a images the same class and just changing the .jpg to _hover.jpg but they are not changing to the right image. They all change to the same one hover image not their own.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You must of name the image wrong, changing them to the same class is the way to go since you are ding the exact same thing to all of them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Target all the images, or give them a common class and use that as a selector, and just do the replace inside the function on the fly:

```
$('#index_container img').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        this.src = this.src.replace('.jpg', '_hover.jpg');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        this.src = this.src.replace('_hover.jpg', '.jpg');
    }
});
```

Comment: It is so simple! I was trying to make it more complicated than I needed to. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ChristieDeLucaEllis - you're welcome. Remember to accept the answer if it helped you out, and welcome back when more problems surface, and they always do.